# How to have proper spacing between items in the navbar regardless of word size?

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to CSS and website design itself.
I am creating a website and so far I have only got till the nav bar of it which includes buttons like Home, Contact Us, etc. 
Till now I have gotten till each of them being vertically aligned center and having a text aligned center. But I don't understand even after several searching how to get the spacing right when I have width in percentage of everything and nothing is fixed. (This I have done to make the webpage dynamically change with different resolutions)

[image: This is how it looks on my computer]

As you can see the `HOME` is rightly spaced from the left and you see that there is too small a gap between `Committees` and `RESOURCES`. Also, importantly, the `CONTACT US` has too little room on the left.

Here's the JSFiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhj3m9er/)

Also, zoom out to 50% on JSFiddle if they all get cramped up to see changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.nb_item
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
  padding:0px 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Instead of giving a width of 12.5%, give the width:auto, and then add a padding. and as far as cramping is concenred you need to use media queries,
where if the the width is less than a particular width you need to show them as a drop down list instead of navbar.

Comment: It worked flawlessly. The only concern I have is will the padding in pixels cause any problem?

Comment: ideally you should be giving mesurements in pixels, beacuse % you cant determine the pixels, and in html even a single pixel difference can makes element go crazy.. so by giving mesauremnts in pixels you have a better control, and idea that how many pixels are being used, and if an elements dis aligns  then you can figure out who is taking the extra pixels.

Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: I know. But the situation is so that I have to make it work having exact same ratios on even different devices. With the minimal knowledge I have, I knew that % is the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: you might also want to look into "box-sizing" property, what it is and why it can be useful to use it. :)

Comment: As i said for device compatibilty, you will have to use media query, becuse it wont be possible to show all the name in a single line without being cramped, if its a smaller device, you need to view them as a list.

I will provide you with media query links.

Comment: Thanks :) Will surely look into it. What if I want to make my website mobile compatible? Then also this method is used?

Comment: yes, even for mobile compatibilty, you need to use media queries, basically what media queries does is, you specify a width at which you will use a different set of css of a particualr element, which helps in maintaining the compatibilty.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove width in ".nb_item" and add padding to left and right for equal spacing.

```
    .nb_item
    {
      display:inline-block;
     padding:0px 10px;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     margin:auto;
     text-align:center;
       }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhj3m9er/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove width from the below class and try.

```
.nb_item{

}
```